# Relacionar inputs dinamicos com datalist a outros inputs dinamicos

Tags: javascript, input, dinâmico

sou novo por aqui e curioso na programação, então desculpe se falar besteira, mas preciso de ajuda.

Tenho um formulário com a opção de inserir inputs dinamicamente.
Sempre que se adiciona um "item", são adicionados dois inputs, o *"foo"* e o *"bar"*.
Todos os *"foo"* se relacionam com o datalist *"list"*.
Todos os *"bar"* são inativos e seu valor deve ser alterado sempre quando o valor de *"foo"* for alterado.

HTML INPUTS:

```
<div id="lista">
  <div>
    <input name="foo[]" list="dList" type="text">
    <inpu name="bar[]" disabled="" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="foo[]" list="dList" type="text">
    <inpu name="bar[]" disabled="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<datalist id="dList">
  <option label="Item 1" datavalue="1" value="Item 1">
  <option label="Item 2" datavalue="2" value="Item 2">
</datalist>
```

A única maneira que encontrei de pegar os inputs (dinamicos) foi:

```
input = $('#listaServicos').find(':input'); // array de inputs
// aqui tereis tanto os _"foo"_ quanto os _"bar"_
```

E depois fazer um `for` trabalhando com eles:

```
valores = [[1,3000],[2,5000],[3,4000],[4,10000],[5,10000]];

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  name = input[i].name;
  console.log("name: "+ name);
  if(name.indexOf('foo') > -1){
    // aqui preciso pegar o atributo _"datavalue"_ do datalist 
    // correspondente, comparar com a key array valores
    //e preencher o _"bar"_ com o valor
  }
}
```

O problema maior esta em relacionar o *"foo"* com o datalist, pois o *"foo"* e o *"bar"* estarão sempre no mesmo subarray.

Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda quer vier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma alternativa de implementação do que entendi do problema, com certeza existem maneiras melhores de implementar, o código está bem auto-explicativo mas segue uma breve descrição do que ele faz:
Primeiramente coloquei a função `.on('input')` do jquery que é acionada sempre que o `input` for alterado, logo em seguida pego o valor selecionado e procuro ele no datalist(`dList`) através do [seletor jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), com o valor de fato procuro pela chave correspondente no array de `valores[]`, após encontrar simplesmente atribuo o valor no input `bar` com o [siblings jquery](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

*Nota que o código só funciona nesse **formato do array valores**, tentei alterar mínimo possível, qualquer dúvida comenta ai, espero que ajude.

```js
//input = $('#listaServicos').find(':input'); // array de inputs
// aqui tereis tanto os _"foo"_ quanto os _"bar"_

valores = [
  [1, 3000],
  [2, 5000],
  [3, 4000],
  [4, 10000],
  [5, 10000]
];

$('input').on('input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var chaveSelecionada = $('#dList [value="' + value + '"]').data('value');
  var valorDaChaveNoArray = procuraPorChave(chaveSelecionada);
  $(this).siblings("input").val(valorDaChaveNoArray);

});

function procuraPorChave(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      if (valores[i][j] == id) {
        return valores[i][j + 1];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista">
  <div>
    <input name="foo[]" list="dList" type="text">
    <input name="bar[]" disabled="" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="foo[]" list="dList" type="text">
    <input name="bar[]" disabled="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<datalist id="dList">
  <option label="Item 1" data-value="1" value="Item 1">
  <option label="Item 2" data-value="2" value="Item 2">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Grande resposta!!!
Grato pela ajuda, não esperava uma resposta tão precisa e rápida!

Comment: Adicionalmente, toda vez que um input é adicionado, tenho que REexecutar o trecho "$('input').on('input', function() {....}" para que funcione nos novos inputs.